# Prove there exist a complex number that satisfies the given conditions

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that there exists a complex number $z=a+ib$ on the complex plane such that there are no two complex numbers $z_1=x_1+i y_1$ and $z_2=x_2+i y_2$ such that $\left|z_1-z\right|=\left|z_2-z\right|$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

---

I assumed the contrary, hence I tried using distance formula to get $\left(x_1-a\right)^2+\left(y_1-b\right)^2=\left(x_2-a\right)^2+\left(y_2-b\right)^2 \implies \left(x_1-x\right)\left(x_1+x_2-2 a\right)=\left(y_2-y\right)\left(y_2+y_1-2 b\right)$. Here, $x_1-x, x_1+x_2, y_2-y, y_2+y_1$ are all integers while $2a,2b$ aren't necessarily integers. My aim was to look for some contradiction, but I can't progress from here.

Comment: You can probably proceed as follows. Suppose for now that we will choose $a,b$ to be irrational. Consider the case where $y_1 =y_2$. Then, in order for $(x_1 - x_2)(x_1 + x_2 + 2a)=0,$ you must have $x_1 + x_2 = 2a$ (otherwise the two points are the same if $x_1 = x_2$), but then $x_1, x_2$ cannot both be integers since $a$ is irrational. Thus there exist no solution.

Now for the second case, where $y_1 \neq y_2,$ you can divide both sides of the equation to get $$\frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1} = \frac{y_1+y_2 -2b}{x_1 + x_2 - 2a}.$$ Because all of the $x_i, y_i,$ are integers, (continued)

Comment: this means that the LHS is rational. Now, you can choose some irrational numbers $a,b$ so that the RHS must be irrational (for example, maybe you could consider choosing $a = \sqrt{2}$ and then multiplying the numerator and denominator on the RHS by $(x_1 + x_2 + 2a)$ to cancel out the irrational part in the denominator, and you can choose $b$ so that the resulting thing must be irrational). Then this would suffice for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

For two points on the real or complex plane, the set of points that are equidistant from both of them lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining the two points.

For the $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ grid in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, there will be a perpendicular bisector for any two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$. The set of perpendicular bisectors for two points of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ will be of cardinality $|\mathbb Z^4|=\aleph_0$ and therefore, it's union can't cover all of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (lines are of measure zero). So, there is a point that satisfies said requirement.

Comment: What does $|\mathbb Z^4|=\aleph_0$  mean?

Comment: The set is countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answers the original problem, but perhaps not OP's question. But it's too long for a comment.

*Claim*: The complex number $\ z = \pi + i\frac{1}{\pi}\ $ satisfies the conditions.

*Proof:* Let $\ z = \pi + i\frac{1}{\pi}\ $ and suppose there *are* two complex numbers $z_1=x_1+i y_1$ and $z_2=x_2+i y_2$ such that $\left|z_1-z\right|=\left|z_2-z\right|$ where $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then we have:

$$ (\pi - x_1 )^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\pi} - y_1 \right)^2 = (\pi - x_2 )^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\pi} - y_2 \right)^2. $$

Expanding, simplifying and rearranging, we get:

$$ 2(x_2-x_1)\pi + (y_2-y_1)\frac{2}{\pi} + ({x_1}^2 + {y_1}^2 - {x_2}^2 - {y_2}^2) = 0 $$

Multiplying through by $\ \pi,\ $ we see that $\ u=\pi\ $ satisfies the quadratic equation with rational coefficients:

$$  2(x_2-x_1)u^2 + ({x_1}^2 + {y_1}^2 - {x_2}^2 - {y_2}^2)u + 2(y_2-y_1) = 0,$$

contradicting the [transcendence of $\ \pi.$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) So our assumption that two such numbers $\ z_1,\ z_2\ $ exist is false. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But are $\ z = \pi + i\frac{1}{\pi}\ $ the only ones who satisfy the conditions?

Comment: No, there are many more examples. For example, if $\ \alpha\ $ is transcendental, then $\ z = \alpha + i\frac{k}{\alpha},\ $ for any $\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$ works as it follows the exact same argument as my answer. And since "most numbers" (in some sense) are transcendental, this gives many examples. And I'm sure there are many, many, many other types of examples. I have just given one example, which is what the original problem was asking for.